# Lego Control plus doesn't work with Cat D11 Bulldozer (42131)

Tags: technic, powered-up, control-plus

When I am testing my remote control for the [Cat D11 Bulldozer (42131)](https://brickset.com/sets/42131-1/Cat-D11-Bulldozer) all features are working except the two motors for the wheels. Also when I am syncing the CONTROL+ app nothing is working. I have tested the motors with BrickController 2 app and the motors are working perfect. I also installed the CONTROL+ app on another device (tablet) with no result. I tested it also with the motors connected directly with the hub, no result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same here ! Finally you found a solution !?